# android remove category.BROWSABLE from <intent-filter>?

Tags: android, url, android-manifest

In my app, I set up an Intent to use the default SMS app on user A's device to send a SMS text and a small amount of plain/text data.  It is sent to user B's device and received in their default SMS app.  A clickable link in the SMS text can be clicked on by user B to launch the app on their device and receive in the plain/text data.

When user B clicks on the link, a chooser dialog opens to show the icon for my app and for the Chrome Browser.  How do I remove the choice of the Chrome browser, as I only want the text and small amount of data to be delivered to my app for the user?

If I leave out the 'category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"' in the intent-filter of DetailsActivity in the AndroidManifest, then Android Studio throws this warning error  "Activity supporting ACTION_VIEW is not set as BROWSABLE."

User B's Activity and intent-filter in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"  >
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                 android:value=".MainActivity"  />  
      <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="myapp"
                  android:pathPrefix="/launchapp"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
   
MainActivity
...
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String phoneMsg = "here's a new card:\n" + "http://myapp/launchapp";
if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing#associatesite

Comment: @CommonWare Thanks, I read that but I do not have the app's domain finalized yet so will not have the ability to add App Links.  I am looking for a solution without setting up via App Links.

Comment: Use a scheme that Web browsers won't recognize (`ajw://`), bearing in mind that the SMS client might not recognize it either. Otherwise, you don't really have much choice.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately ajw:// or similar removes the clickable link.

Comment: Would a custom Action help rather than action.VIEW?

Comment: Unless you are writing your own SMS client, you do not have control over the SMS client and what `Intent` action it uses.